Drag and drop function doesn't work as expected
const Boards = () => {
  let [color, setColor] = useState("#7C3AED");
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);
  const columnsId = useMemo(
    () => columns?.map((col) => col.id) ?? [],
    [columns]
  );

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [activeColumn, setActiveColumn] = useState(null);
  const [activeTask, setActiveTask] = useState(null);

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  const {
    selectedProject,
    setSelectedProject,
    selectedBoard,
    setSelectedBoard,
  } = useBoardStore();

  const { data, error, isLoading } = useCustomQuery(
    ["Boardlist", selectedBoard],
    `/projectboard/${selectedBoard}/info`,
    {},
    {
      enabled: !!selectedBoard,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data?.projectboard?.columns);
    setColumns(data?.projectboard?.columns || []);
  }, [data]);

  const onDragStart = (event) => {
    setActiveColumn(null);
    setActiveTask(null);
    if (event.active.data.current?.type === "Column") {
      setActiveColumn(event.active.data.current.column);
    }
    if (event.active.data.current?.type === "Task") {
      setActiveTask(event.active.data.current.task);
    }
  };


  const onDragEnd = (event) => {
    const { active, over } = event;

    if (!over) return;

    const activeColumnId = active.data.current?.column?.id;
    const overColumnId = over.data.current?.column?.id;
    const activeTaskId = active.data.current?.task?.id;

    // If it's a task being dragged
    if (activeTaskId) {
      const activeTask = tasks.find((t) => t.id === activeTaskId);

      // If the task is dropped in the same column
      if (activeColumnId === overColumnId) {
        const activeTaskIndex = tasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === activeTaskId);
        const overTaskIndex = 
          over.data.current?.task 
            ? tasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === over.data.current?.task?.id) 
            : -1; 

        if (overTaskIndex === -1) {
          // Handle the case where there is no task being hovered over
          const updatedTasks = [...tasks]; 
          const activeTaskIndex = updatedTasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === activeTaskId);
          updatedTasks.splice(activeTaskIndex, 1); 
          updatedTasks.push(activeTask); 
          setTasks(updatedTasks); 
        } else {
          const updatedTasks = arrayMove(tasks, activeTaskIndex, overTaskIndex);
          setTasks(updatedTasks);
        }
      } else {
        // Task is moved between columns, so update its columnId
        const updatedTasks = tasks.filter((t) => t.id !== activeTaskId);

        const movedTask = { ...activeTask, columnId: overColumnId }; // Update columnId

        // If the target column is empty, directly add the task to the column
        setTasks([...updatedTasks, movedTask]);

        // Additionally, update the columns if necessary (for visual consistency)
        setColumns((prevColumns) => {
          const updatedColumns = [...prevColumns];
          const overColumn = updatedColumns.find(
            (col) => col.id === overColumnId
          );

          // Add the moved task to the over column
          if (overColumn) {
            overColumn.tasks.push(movedTask); // Add the task to the target column
          }

          return updatedColumns;
        });
      }
    }

    // If it's a column being dragged (changing the order of columns)
    if (activeColumnId && overColumnId && activeColumnId !== overColumnId) {
      setColumns((columns) => {
        const activeIndex = columns.findIndex(
          (col) => col.id === activeColumnId
        );
        const overColumnIndex = columns.findIndex(
          (col) => col.id === overColumnId
        );
        return arrayMove(columns, activeIndex, overColumnIndex);
      });
    }
  };

  const onDragOver = (event) => {
    const { active, over } = event;

    if (!active || !over) return;

    const activeId = active.id;
    const overId = over.id;

    if (activeId === overId) return;

    const activeData = active.data.current;
    const overData = over.data.current;

    if (!activeData || !overData) {
      console.warn("Active or over data is missing.");
      return;
    }

    // Handle task dragging
    if (activeData.type === "Task" && overData.type === "Task") {
      const activeTaskData = activeData.task;
      const overTaskData = overData.task;

      if (!activeTaskData || !overTaskData) {
        console.warn("Active or over task data is missing.");
        return;
      }

      const activeColumnId = activeTaskData.columnId;
      const overColumnId = overTaskData.columnId;

      if (!activeColumnId || !overColumnId) {
        console.warn("Active or over column not found.");
        return;
      }

      // Ensure columns state is initialized properly
      setColumns((prevColumns) => {
        if (!prevColumns) {
          console.warn("Columns state is not defined.");
          return []; // Return empty if no columns exist
        }

        const activeColumn = prevColumns.find(
          (col) => col.id === activeColumnId
        );
        const overColumn = prevColumns.find((col) => col.id === overColumnId);

        if (!activeColumn || !overColumn) {
          console.warn("Active or over column not found in state.");
          return prevColumns;
        }

        const activeTaskIndex = activeColumn.tasks.findIndex(
          (task) => task.id === activeId
        );

        if (activeTaskIndex === -1) {
          console.warn("Active task not found in the active column.");
          return prevColumns;
        }

        const updatedColumns = [...prevColumns];

        if (activeColumnId === overColumnId) {
          // Reorder tasks within the same column
          const overTaskIndex = 
            over.data.current?.task 
              ? overColumn.tasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === over.data.current?.task?.id) 
              : -1; 
          const updatedTasks = arrayMove(
            activeColumn.tasks,
            activeTaskIndex,
            overTaskIndex
          );
          updatedColumns.forEach((col) => {
            if (col.id === activeColumnId) col.tasks = updatedTasks;
          });
        } else {
          // Move task to a different column
          const [movedTask] = activeColumn.tasks.splice(activeTaskIndex, 1);
          movedTask.columnId = overColumnId; // Update task's columnId

          // Always add the moved task to the overColumn
          overColumn.tasks = [...overColumn.tasks, movedTask]; 

          updatedColumns.forEach((col) => {
            if (col.id === activeColumnId) col.tasks = [...activeColumn.tasks];
            if (col.id === overColumnId) col.tasks = [...overColumn.tasks];
          });
        }

        return updatedColumns;
      });
    }
  };
 



  const sensors = useSensors(
    useSensor(PointerSensor, {
      activationConstraint: {
        distance: 5,
      },
    })
  );
  


Hello all i am working with react and dnd kit for building a kanban board the issue is everything works fine but if i drag the card to a empty list the card not getting added  rest all time its working
I am attaching my full code below
Link to code
Also my json is in format a below
project:[
task1:{},task2:{} ]
